# Writing Application config files on APK install

Tags: android, configuration, storage

Is it possible to automatically write my own config files upon installation of an APK? How do I do that? I realize this might introduce unwanted bugs as user can change these configs. However, I need this functionality in my Android app. I don't want the application to run first then write the file. What I really want is writing my own config files upon installation. Can anybody give pointers? Thanks.

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way.  Please focus on what you are trying to achieve - the **why** - rather than the how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really want is writing my own config files upon installation.

That is not possible. There is no hook in Android to automatically set up some sort of files on internal storage. And, if you are "writing [your] own config files", then **by definition**, then "the application [will] run first", because your application is where the file-writing code resides.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks a lot for the info. Hm. I really should rethink this through. So basically what I was trying to achieve is: Since my application connects to a certain server with certain IP, what if the IP of the server has changed, but I have no possible ways to re-install the application from my side. I would like my application to be able to connect to the server with the new IP just be changing a certain configuration file.

Comment: @NicholasLie: Having a configuration file is fine. However, that configuration file needs to be editable (which means it probably needs to be on external storage). And you will need to set up the configuration file on the first run of your device, or if you determine that the configuration file is missing (e.g., the user deleted it). You can package a "starter" configuration file in `assets/` and copy that out when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files? If its related to the APK of your app then chances are, it is gonna be the run first then write the file. A thing for writing file though is the assets folder that an android project has.